# Is the factory design pattern used in a Java API?

Tags: java, design-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Examples of GoF Design Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns)

Is there a Java API class which follows the [factory design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)?

Comment: see [BalusC's answer to the above question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns/2707195#2707195). Pure beauty!

Answer (score 3):

[`class.newInstance();`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29)

[`Integer.valueOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the online [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).

Use your web browser's page search to search for "Factory".  (It's Control-F and Control-G on most of them.)

Answer (score 0):

[BorderFactory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at `SAXParserFactory.` It is a factory class which can be used to intantiate SAX based parsers to pares XML. The method `newInstance` is the factory method which instantiates the sax parsers based on some predefined logic.